# projection of a point into a line (3d)

Tags: geometry

**3 dimensional case**

I have line defined by 2 points: A and B
and I have defined point P somewhere.

I would like to find the point R on line AB assuming that the line AB is perpendicular to PR line.

**Solution must be pattern(s) applicable in spreadsheets (Excel etc.).**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the Points A,B,P and R be $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{p}$ and $\vec{r}$.

since $\vec{r}$ lies in line AB, by line equation,

$\vec{r}= \vec{a} -t.(\vec{b}-\vec{a})$ ------ 1

where $t$ is a constant

since line AB is Perpendicular to PR

$$(\vec{a}-\vec{b}).(\vec{p}-\vec{r})=0$$

$$\vec{p}.(\vec{a}-\vec{b})=\vec{r}.(\vec{a}-\vec{b})$$

if you substitute $\vec{r}$ in 1 we get 
$$\vec{p}.(\vec{a}-\vec{b})=[\vec{a} -t.(\vec{b}-\vec{a})].(\vec{a}-\vec{b})$$

if you substitute the value of P, A and B we can get the value of $t$

if you back-substitute the values of $t$ we would get the point R

Comment: t = ( (p-a).(a-b) ) / (a-b).(a-b) **This is right, right?**

Comment: yes @Fanda that is the right answer